# Can you set AngularFire to store a specific collection on a device?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

The question: can you save a specific Firebase collection on a mobile device?

Longer explanation:  I am building an app to capture data while I am out in the field.  The problem is that we have bad mobile connections and it will not change soon.  We have wifi at home, so every evening the data can be sent to Firebase.

However, I will need some critical data while out in the field.  So, I want to store that data on my mobile phone, the rest can be loaded and cached the way AngularFire do at the moment.

I am building the app with Ionic and Capacitor.

Comment: Check - [https://github.com/angular/angularfire/..](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/offline-data.md)

Comment: Thank you @AkshayaJeevan, I implemented persistence.  However, they use a cache method.  So you have to open the data on the device first before it is cached.

This is fine for most features in my app, but there are some specific data that should always be available. They should always be saved.  I guess I have to work with the cache settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SQLite? it's a great way to store data in the phone if you don't want to frequently fetch data from firebase